# How to import a ES2015 JavaScript module in an Ember.js project?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6

I want to use a JavaScript module (ES2015) in my Ember.js project, but it does not work.

I wrote a simple sample ES6 JavaScript file,

myES6lib.js

```
export default function square(b) {
  return b * b;
};
```

Following the [MANAGEMENT DEPENDENCES](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies), I ran

```
ember generate vendor-shim myES6lib
```

and added a line in ember-cli-build.js

```
app.import("vendor/shims/myES6lib.js");
```

then I called the square function in an Ember Controller

```
import MyES6lib from "myES6lib";
...
console.log("Square(5) = " + MyES6lib.square(5));
```

but I got an error message as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _myES6lib.default.square is not a function
```

Any hints are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Note: I tried to transform myES6lib to ES5 code by Babel, but the result was same.

Comment: You only ever need a vendor shim for bower packages, is your module a bower package?

Comment: Thank you Kitler. I think my module is not a bower package, it just a js file.

Comment: At this time I can use my own code as an utility file in my Ember.js  project according to the way shown in your answer. I'll learn the bower package as you mentioned, I think it should be transformed to a bower package if I want to share my code in other project.  last could you tell me the reason you deleted ES6 tag，thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function looks more like a utility function, move it to `yourApp/utils/square`, you don't need to name the function in this case since it is the only one in the file:

```
export default function(b) {
  return b * b;
};
```

And then just import it in your file:

```
import myCustomSquare from 'myApp/utils/square';
```

And use it `myCustomSquare(2);`

Multiple functions in a file:

You would follow the same logic as for a single file except inside the file you would export each function:

```
export function square(b) {
  //your logic goes here 
}

export function myOtherCustomFunction(b) {
  //your logic goes here 
}
```

And from your controller/anywhere else you would import it like so:

`import { square, myOtherCustomFunction } from 'myApp/utils/myCustomFunctions'`

Comment: Thank you Kitler. This file will include other functions and I want use this file in ember.js project (there is not a utils folder.

Comment: @Calvin In that case I ll update the answer, you can create the utils folder it doesn't come with the boilerplate

Comment: @Kitler @Calvin You can generate the boilerplate. `ember g util square` This also conveniently creates a test.

Comment: Good morning Kitler, thank you very much. I tried it and it worked. I also tried "import Mylib from "myApp/utils/Mylib" and called the function like "console.log(Mylib.square(5))", it also worked well.

Comment: I ran `ember g util mylib`, a test.js file is created. Very convenient! Thank you  Kitler.

Answer (score 2):

Your default export is the `square` function, therefore rather than calling it like this:

```
console.log("Square(5) = " + MyES6lib.square(5));
```

You need to call it like this:

```
console.log("Square(5) = " + MyES6lib(5));
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. I tried. but it did not work. The error message became: "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _MyES6lib.default) is not a function".

Comment: I also tried “import {square} from "myES6lib";” and “+ square(5)", then the error message became: "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _import.square) is not a function".

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Hopefully someone will chime in with a solution then, I don't why that shouldn't work D: